Control a non-affine system
I have a question about the control of a non-affine system.
Here is my system
$\dot{x} = a(u) + b(u) . u$
\begin{equation}\label{a_beta}
a(u) = 0.22 \left( 
\frac{116(u^3 + 1)-4.06 \lambda }{(\lambda + 0.08u)(u^3 + 1)} -5
\right)
\exp \left( -\frac{12.5}{\Gamma} \right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{b_beta}
b(u) = 0.22 \left( 
- 0.4   
-\frac{0.3248}{(\lambda + 0.08u)(u^3 + 1)} \right)
\exp \left( -\frac{12.5}{\Gamma} \right)
\end{equation}
also
\begin{equation}
\Gamma = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\lambda + 0.08u}\right) - \left(\frac{0.035}{u^3 + 1}\right)}
\end{equation}
such that $\lambda$ is a positive constant number.
Do you have any idea how to handle this non-affine system?
I would be grateful if someone reply to this question.

Depends on what you mean by "handle this ... system". You could always try to linearize the system and get a controller for that system. Then if you are lucky and your initial conditions are close enough to the equilibrium it will stabilize it.
